# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file error "txt database"

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, io

Hey guys still here :)

I get ValueError: I/O operation on closed file error.

```
db = open(r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\db.txt", "a+")
print("""-Type 1 for add film
-Type 2 for see your films
""")
while True:
    enter = input("Please Enter: ")

    if enter == "1":
        film=input("Enter film: ")
        db.write(film + "\n")
        db.close()

    elif enter == "2":
        print("Your's films: ")
        db.seek(0)
        print(db.read())

        db.close()



    elif giris == "":
        print("Please type something!")


    else:
        print("Error!")
```

When I enter 1, I add film and I enter 2 again for see my films.I get ValueError: I/O operation on closed file error :(

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `db.close()` in your `while` loop, which closes the file between iterations. This is the source of your error. I would move `db.close()` to the end of your script. This is more efficient than re-opening the file every iteration.

If you need the output to be flushed while iterating through the loop, use [flush()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush), i.e. `db.flush()`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is exactly what it says. You're trying to write to the file after you've closed it. There are two solutions:

1. Move the `close()` calls outside of the loop.

   ```
   while True:
       # do stuff

   db.close()
   ```
2. Open the file inside the loop.

   ```
   while True:
       db = open(r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\db.txt", "a+")
       ...
   ```